# How to connect seekbar in Activity with player in Service?

Tags: java, android

So I have a service that creates, plays and handles a mediaplayer (just audio), yet I have a seekbar in the main activity that I want to, naturally, show the progress of the audio file and allow the user to seek to various positions.

What I'm having a hell of a time figuring out is: what would be the best or proper way to connect the seekbar in the UI to the mediaplayer in the service?

Do I need a remote view?

Do I want to just bind the activity to the service? (and then how would I connect the seekbar?)

Do I want to simply keep throwing values back and forth using OnSharedPreferencesListener?

First of all Java is foreign to me as I only studied C/C++ and the Basics (literally Basic and Visual Basic) years ago. So because I don't have a solid grasp on these things I will be studying Java more in depth, but as of right now, I could really use a bit of insight as to what I should do, this app needs to get finished soon. I'd really appreciate any help anyone can give!

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to bind the activity to the service. Then you can receive data from it to build the view. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#servlife